# USB sound card with line in

Tags: usb, audio

I am looking for a usb sound card for my laptop. I mainly use it for my headset so it must have a mic in and a headset out. I also would like to have a line-in port on it to record with. I don't need a card with surround sound output as I only use it with my headset.

The card needs to support both windows 10 and linux.
Ideally under $50.

something like a behringer UCA202:
[https://www.amazon.com/Behringer-UCA202-Audio-Interface/dp/B000KW2YEI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KW2YEI)
would be perfect if it also had a 3.5mm mic input.